# Returning Multiple Data with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There are a couple questions I have regarding the following code:

```
    // Create a new MySQL connection, inserting a host, username, passord, and database you connecting to
    $conn = new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx',);
    if(!$conn) {
        die('Connection Failed: ' . $conn->error());
    }

    // Create and execute a MySQL query
    $sql = "SELECT artist_name FROM artists"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // Loop through the returned data and output it
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf(
            "Artist: %s<br />", $row['artist_name'], "<br />",
            "Profile: %s<br />", $row['artist_dob'], "<br />",
            "Date of Birth: %s<br />", $row['artist_profile'], "<br />",
            "Password: %s<br />", $row['artist_password'], "<br />"
        );
    }

    // Free memory associated with the query
    $result->close();

    // Close connection
    $conn->close();
```

How can I assign `artist_dob`, `artist_profile`, and `artist_password` and return it to the browser?

What does the statement `$conn->error()` mean? I don't understand what the `->` sign does.

Comment: $conn->error will return the error message associated with the reason why the connection failed.

Comment: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

The `printf()` function will return the information to the screen.  The $conn->error() will echo out a database error if there was one trying to connect.  the `->` means it's calling a function from an object so `$conn` is an object and it has lots of functions and `$conn->query()` means to run the query function on the `$conn` object.

You may want to look into beginner php object-oriented tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?q=beginner+guide+to+php+oop

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have checked out the tutorial and I think it's good. Let me check it out more...

Answer (score 1):

This code is all wrong.
What it actually have to be:

```
// Create a new PDO connection to MySQL
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$conn = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);

// Create and execute a MySQL query
$sql = "SELECT artist_name FROM artists"; 
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$data = $stm->fetchAll();

// Loop through the returned data and output it
?>
<? foreach($data as $row): ?>
        Artist: <?=$row['artist_name']?><br />
        Profile: <?=$row['artist_dob']?><br />
        Date of Birth: <?=$row['artist_profile']?><br />
        Password: <?=$row['artist_password']?><br />
<? endforeach ?>
```

And it is in many (at least a dozen) ways better.

Comment: I think you used a different method of connecting to the database, the one I haven't gotten to learn about yet. I was using the MySQLi Method... I know less about PDO, but maybe I should look into it...

Answer (score 0):

The `->` in PHP is used to call methods and public parametres from objects like the `.` in many other languages like C# or Java.

PHP: `$object->method();`

Java: `object.method();`

Also, your concatenate character is wrong. If you use the comma `,` you are passing multiple parametres to the function. To concatenate strings in PHP you have to use the point `.` like in other languages you would use the `+`.

PHP: `"Some "."string"` = "Some string"

Java: `"Some "+"string"` = "Some string"

Of course, you can concatenate strings in the function calling as an argument.

```
$string = "Print".$string;
printf($string);
```

is the same than

`printf("Print ".$string);`

Comment: Incorrect, `printf` allows as many parameters as needed, check the [manual](http://uk3.php.net/printf)